# How to loop through my 2d array?

Tags: python, loops

I have an array which created with this:

```
numbers = []
for num in range(0,5): 
      nums = []
      for inum in range(0,5):
          nums.append(inum) 

      numbers.append(nums)
```

How to loop through? I tried `for item in len(numbers):` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List items are iterable, no need to get length as they will assign themselves to the first variable with for..in.. loops;

```
for item in numbers:
    print "In first list: ", item
    for num in item:
        print "    Getting number: ", num
```

outputs

```
In first list:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    Getting number:  0
    Getting number:  1
    Getting number:  2
    Getting number:  3
    Getting number:  4
In first list:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    Getting number:  0
    Getting number:  1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        print numbers[i][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

Double loop:

```
for row in numbers:
    for cell in row:
        print cell,
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this.

```
[[col for col in range(5)] for row in range(5)]
```